# How do I add global error handling to a chrome extension background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a **`window.onerror()`** function at the top of my background script but this doesn't appear to catch all errors. Here is a reduced version of my background.js

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
  console.log('Caught content script error');
  console.log('errorMsg: ' + errorMsg);
  console.log('url: ' + url);
  console.log('lineNumber: ' + lineNumber);
  console.log('column: ' + column);
  console.log('error object: ', errorObj);
  return true;
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
 // handle incoming message events
}

function helperFunc1() {
  // code here
}

function helperFunc2() {
  // code here
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
 // code here based on tab info
}

...
```

I'm inserting **`throw new Error('this is an error')`** at random points in the background script to test the **window.onerror** function and see if it triggers. It will however only trigger when I throw errors outside of any function or listener, ie in the global scope. Errors that I create inside a function do not trigger **window.onerror**.

Why is that, and what is a good way to catch these errors?

I don't want to have to wrap all bits of code in try catch blocks, that can be tedious to implement and maintain.

Comment: Apparently you can't, see https://crbug.com/357568